# Symfony 4 - Adding childs of CollectionType Form with Jquery not submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, symfony

I have a form on my entity 'OrdreMission' that has childrens entities 'OrdreMissionFraisDivers' with a CollectionType :

**OrdreMission.php** *(the parent class)*

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OrdreMissionRepository")
 */
class OrdreMission 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrdreMissionFraisDivers", mappedBy="ordreMission", 
    cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $fraisDivers;

    /**
     * @return Collection|OrdreMissionFraisDivers[]
     */
    public function getFraisDivers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->fraisDivers;
    }

    public function addFraisDiver(OrdreMissionFraisDivers $fraisDivers): self
    {
        $this->fraisDivers[] = $fraisDivers;
        $fraisDivers->setOrdreMission($this);

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFraisDiver(OrdreMissionFraisDivers $fraisDivers): self
    {
        if ($this->fraisDivers->contains($fraisDivers)) {
             $this->fraisDivers->removeElement($fraisDivers);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($fraisDivers->getOrdreMission() === $this) {
            $fraisDivers->setOrdreMission(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**OrdreMissionFraisDivers.php** *(the child class)*

```
class OrdreMissionFraisDivers
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrdreMission", inversedBy="fraisDivers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
     private $ordreMission;

    public function getOrdreMission(): ?OrdreMission
    {
        return $this->ordreMission;
    }

    public function setOrdreMission(?OrdreMission $ordreMission): self
    {
        $this->ordreMission = $ordreMission;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**OrdreMissionType.php** *(form class of OrdreMission)*

```
class OrdreMissionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('fraisDivers', CollectionType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'entry_type' => OrdreMissionFraisDiversType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => OrdreMission::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

**OrdreMissionFraisDiversType.php** *(form class of OrdreMissionFraisDivers)*

```
class OrdreMissionFraisDiversType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder->add('libelle', TextType::class, [
            'label' => false
        ]);
        $builder->add('montantJour', MoneyType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'mapped' => false,
            'disabled' => true,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'montantJour']
        ]);
        $builder->add('montant', MoneyType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'montantTotal']
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => OrdreMissionFraisDivers::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Creation of the form in my controller**

```
    $odm = new OrdreMission();
    $odmtpe = new OrdreMissionFraisDivers();
    $odmtpe->setLibelle('test')->setMontant(15); 
    $odm->addFraisDiver($odmtpe); //i add a child before creating the form to test the mapping

    $form = $this->createForm(OrdreMissionType::class, $odm,[
        'user' => $user,
        'affairesOdm' => $affairesForm,
        'method' => 'PUT'
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $odm = $form->getData();
        $odm->setEtat('C');
        $odm->setDemandeur($demandeur);
        $odm->setSalarie($user);

       dd($odm);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($odm);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('pages/pointage/odm/creation.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
```

**My View** *(i'm using a prototype to dynamiclly add childs in my form, the problem come from here)*

```
{% macro printFraisDiversRow(fraisDiversForm) %}
    <td>{{ form_row(fraisDiversForm.libelle) }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_row(fraisDiversForm.montantJour) }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_row(fraisDiversForm.montant) }}</td>
{% endmacro %}

<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light fraisDiversHead" style="display: none">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Type d'indemnité</th>
            <th scope="col">Montant (€/jour)</th>
            <th scope="col">Montant (€/mission)</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody class="fraisDivers"  data-prototype="{{ 
          formMacros.printFraisDiversRow(form.fraisDivers.vars.prototype) | e('html_attr') }}">

        </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $collectionHolder = $('tbody.fraisDivers');
        $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);
        $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);
        $addFraisDiversButton.on('click', function(e) {
            addFraisDiversForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
        });
    });

    function addFraisDiversForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
        let thead = $('thead.fraisDiversHead');
        let prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');
        let index = $collectionHolder.data('index');
        let newForm = prototype;
        newForm = newForm.replace(/__name__/g, index);
        $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);
        let $newFormLi = $('<tr></tr>').append(newForm);
        addFraisDiversDeleteLink($newFormLi);
        $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
    };
</script>
```

**My problem is :** When I add a new child to my form, this one is not submitted. I think this is a problem with my prototype or my macro but I don't see what I forgot to do. 
The child that I declared in my controller before creating the form is sent when I submit this one, as you can see in the debug picture.

[image]

Debug after the form submission :

[image]

**Edit :** Here's the DOM generated with the children at the bottom of the form :

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <div id="ordre_mission_fraisDivers">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div id="ordre_mission_fraisDivers_0">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="ordre_mission_fraisDivers_0_libelle" name="ordre_mission[fraisDivers][0][libelle]" required="required" class="form-control" value="test">
                    </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="input-group">
                         <input type="text" id="ordre_mission_fraisDivers_0_montantJour" name="ordre_mission[fraisDivers][0][montantJour]" disabled="disabled" required="required" class="montantJour form-control">
                         <div class="input-group-append">
                             <span class="input-group-text"> €</span>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="input-group">
                         <input type="text" id="ordre_mission_fraisDivers_0_montant" name="ordre_mission[fraisDivers][0][montant]" required="required" class="montantTotal form-control" value="15,00"> 
                             <div class="input-group-append">
                                 <span class="input-group-text"> €</span>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </fieldset>
         </div>
 </fieldset>
```

The DOM generated on the table (after adding 1 child) :

```
<table class="table">
    <!-- thead -->
    <tbody class="fraisDivers" data-prototype="<!-- prototype generated -->">
        <tr>    
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="ordre_mission_fraisDivers_1_libelle" name="ordre_mission[fraisDivers][1][libelle]" required="required" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="ordre_mission_fraisDivers_1_montantJour" name="ordre_mission[fraisDivers][1][montantJour]" disabled="disabled" required="required" class="montantJour form-control">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"> €</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="ordre_mission_fraisDivers_1_montant" name="ordre_mission[fraisDivers][1][montant]" required="required" class="montantTotal form-control">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"> €</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary add_tag_link">
                <i class="fas fa-plus" style="margin-right: 5px"></i> 
                Ajouter un frais
            </button>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I believe the problem **could** be similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58556002/new-collection-element-overwrites-the-last-element-if-it-already-exists-when-upd/58577369#58577369 in any case: you should take a good look at the generated dom/html and the `name`s of the form elements you create. you omit the code, where the existing children are rendered ...

Comment: I updated my question by adding the generated DOM. As you can see, names & ids are correctly generated in both cases.

Comment: this might be a stupid question, but is that created stuff also inside the `<form>`?